# PHP ziparchive fails to open PPSX extension (failed, code:9)

Tags: php, powerpoint, slideshow, openxml, php-ziparchive

Processing the text from a PPTX extension works perfectly, but if a PP**S**X sits on the same URL (same server & permissions) the code throws code:9 error (ER_NOENT). Can someone help determine why a PPTX vs a PPSX is treated differently though they are both the same openXML standard? How can I extract the text from a PPSX file?

For reference the mime-type is: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow

```
<?php   

if(isset($_POST['processFile']) && isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    $fileText = ppsx_to_text($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
}

function ppsx_to_text( $path_to_file )
{
    $zip_handle = new ZipArchive();
    $response   = '';

    if (true === $zip_handle->open($path_to_file)) // <-- fails to open / recognize PPSX as zip***
    {
        $slide_number = 1; //loop through slide files
        $doc = new DOMDocument();

        while (($xml_index = $zip_handle->locateName('ppt/slides/slide' . $slide_number . '.xml')) !== false) 
        {
            $xml_data   = $zip_handle->getFromIndex($xml_index);

            $doc->loadXML($xml_data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            $response  .= strip_tags($doc->saveXML());

            $slide_number++;
        }
        $zip_handle->close();
    }
    return $response;
}

?>

<form id="content_form" class="the_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
   <button type="submit" value="processFile" name="processFile">Process</button>
   <div><?php echo $fileText;?></div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not reproducible from the sample code and description. Chances are high the file functions are right, and the file does not exist at the given location.

Comment: @mario, I am working on a proprietary system so I cannot point to a file on that site in a public forum. You can test the code by instantiating the variable: $path_to_file = "www.example.com/test.ppsx"; and calling the function. I have a personal site which I can upload to tonight. The files are present, because I put them there. If I put the URL in any browser it will download, so I know it is a good link.

Comment: @mario, I said I couldn't point you to a file, it's proprietary. Read the comment again. ANYHOW. There were a few issues with the code: first, it requires the enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag. After, I was still getting hit or miss data on the text extraction. Like most people, I don't control my hosting server settings so visibility was good for 'uploaded' DOCX files but not PPSX files. To get past the visibility issue, instead of post-processing I passed the $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] temp file in memory for processing and now it works. I hope this helps someone else...

Comment: And thank you nickrouty for the base code: https://gist.github.com/nickrouty/6f5ed07e79d2223b279fc5e662264b10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have access to the server (assuming it's windows) take a look at these settings :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types

Your problem may be with how the mime types are configured and served at request. If it is Linux, look up those platform specific settings. If you can't control the server, then your only other option is to access a local copy or memory copy as you have done.